# Hive: CREATE TABLE on unicode csv files

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight, hortonworks-data-platform

On HDInsight cluster, trying to create Hive table on unicode csv files.

```
Invoke-Hive -Query @"
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestUnicode(Numeric1 INT,Numeric2 INT,Numeric3 INT,Name String)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION
'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/TestUnicode.csv';
"@
```

But Hive is not recognising unicode strings properly. Also all integer fields are loaded as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Change encoding of TestUnicode.csv to UTF-8. Works for me.